# function not working, but properly coded

Tags: php, function

Here is my code...
for the function
It doesn't update activation.

```
function activate($email, $email_code){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);


    mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `activated` = 0"), 0) == 1)
    if(mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `activated` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'")){
        return true;
        }
    else{
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: what exactly is this function supposed to do ?

Comment: Please use mysqli instead of mysql, as it is deprecated now.

Comment: If it's _"properly coded"_ then how can we help?

Comment: `mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `activated` = 0"), 0) == 1)` How is that `properly coded`?

Comment: it is supposed to update the user activation from 0 to 1 in the db.

Comment: Take it up with the answer given below then.

Comment: had to add '1' around the 1 variable. Thanks "pros".

Answer (score 0):

you should remove quotes when you put variable, for example:

```
"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = " 
+ $email 
+ " AND `email_code` = " 
+ $email_code 
+ " AND `activated` = 0"

"UPDATE `users` SET `activated` = 1 WHERE `email` = " + $email
```

Comment: The `+` signs actually makes it worse. We're not doing math here.